# Append Data to a Class with variable and child

Tags: javascript

I want to append data in child-div, But Unable to do.
Here is my code:

```
var year = thisYear + i;

$('.parent'+year .child-div).append("some text");
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code?

Comment: <div class="parent2017">
     <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>

Comment: does this class has dot(" . ") on its starting ??

Comment: No... Its Typo. My

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parent1 = $('.parent1');

parent1.children().first().append('some text');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var year = thisYear + i;

$('.parent'+year+' .child-div').append("some text");
```